# Passing actual parameters in a spock unit test specification

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

```
org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
Gradle 1.12
Groovy 1.8.6
java
```

Hello,

I am trying to use `spock` with my java application to run unit tests and building with `gradle`.

However, since I am new to spock, I am not sure how I can pass in the actual parameters to get a correct output?

This is the function signature I want to test, which takes in an inputStream, char[], and a String:

```
public String makeRequest(InputStream keystoreFilename, char[] keystorePassword, String cnn_url) {
    ...
}
```

So in my test specification, I want to pass the keystore file as an inputStream where the actual keystore is located here ../resources/keystore.bks, and the actual password for the keystore and the url to where the web service is. However, I get this error when trying to run the unit test:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sunsystem.HttpSnapClient.SnapClientTest.FileInputStream()
```

My specification test is below, but I think I am going about this the wrong way.

```
import spock.lang.Specification;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class SnapClientTest extends Specification {
    def 'Connect to https web service'() {
        setup:
        def snapzClient = new SnapzClient();

        def inputStream = FileInputStream("../resources/keystore.bks")
        def keystorePwd = "password".toCharArray()
        def url = "https://example_webservice.com"

    expect: 'success when all correct parameters are used'
        snapzClient.makeRequest(A, B, C) == RESULT

        where:
        A           | B           | C   | RESULT
        inputStream | keystorePwd | url | 0
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The title is currently "Passing actual parameters in a spock unit test specification".  This question doesn't really have anything to do with parameter passing.  You should give the question a title which better describes what is being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `where` part accepts only static or shared fields. Or else the value need to be a hard coded literal. So when I modified the class to make the parameters shared it worked for me. Please try this

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class SnapClientTest extends Specification {

    @Shared def inputStream = new FileInputStream("../resources/keystore.bks")
    @Shared def keystorePwd = "password".toCharArray()
    @Shared def url = "https://example_webservice.com"

    def "Connect to https web service"() {
        setup:
        def snapzClient = new SnapzClient();

        expect: 
        snapzClient.makeRequest(A, B, C) == RESULT

        where:
        A           | B           | C   | RESULT
        inputStream | keystorePwd | url | "0"
    }
}
```

Please note that the return type of `makeRequest()` method is string. So if you need to enclose the RESULT with double quotes(")

Answer (score 4):

`No such property` issue is due to the `where:` block.

the `where` block first initializes the test fields. 
in your case *inputStream*, *keystorePwd* and *url* are undeclared, that is why you get the `No such property` error.

Either Initialize the fields in the `where` block, remove the `where` block, declare the fields in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `new`

```
def inputStream = new FileInputStream("../resources/keystore.bks")
```

Comment: I added the new. But I don't think that is the problem: As I now get this error: No such property: inputStream

Comment: There's also no need to use `where` block here. You can inline all the variables used in this line `snapzClient.makeRequest(A, B, C) == RESULT`.

Comment: The line I am getting this error is: def inputStream = new FileInputStream("../resources/keystore.bks") The FileInputStream should return a InputStream to the bks file, and that inputStream gets passed to the function I am testing. However, am I allowed to use java syntax in groovy spock testing?